# Can I gray out a <label> when the item associated with it is disabled?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to disable a `label` when the `input` element associated with it is disabled. Here is my code:

```
                <!-- TODO: Gray this label out initially. -->
                <label id="spacesPerIndentLabel">Spaces per indent: 4</label>
                <br>
                <input id="spacesPerIndent" type="text" disabled>
```

I can't figure out how to make the label disabled. I tried putting `disabled` on the label, but had no luck because [`label` isn't an element that supports `disabled`](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_disabled.asp). I also thought of selecting

```
label + input:disabled { ... }
```

but that would select the disabled `input` instead of the `label`. After some further research I found out that CSS has no "previous sibling" selector (like `+` is the "next sibling" selector).

Comment: You can still add `disabled` to your `<label>`, you'd just have to style it with CSS, eg `label[disabled] { opacity: 0.4; }`

Comment: @Phil Oh, I tried using `label:disabled` instead of `[disabled]`. I'll try your suggestion, thanks. Why do you think `:disabled` didn't work?

Comment: Because the [`:disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled) pseudo-class only works on elements that support the `disabled` property. `[disabled]` is using an attribute selector

Answer (score 3):

You could use css flexbox to position your elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/c1d81r8b/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <input id="test1" type="text">
  <label for="test1">Test 1 label</label>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <input id="test2" type="text" disabled>
  <label for="test2">Test 2 label</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container label {
  order: 1;
}

.container input {
  order: 2;
}

.container input[disabled] + label {
  background: grey;
}
```

This lets your use CSS to set the order the elements are displayed in, and allows you to use the sibling selector.

See https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox for browser support notes.

Comment: This is great, very creative!

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy to add extra attributes or classes to your `<label>` elements, you can use CSS to style them appropriately. For example

```
<label disabled id="spacesPerIndentLabel">Spaces per indent: 4</label>
<!-- or -->
<label class="disabled" id="spacesPerIndentLabel">Spaces per indent: 4</label>
```

your CSS could look like

```
label.disabled, label[disabled] {
  opacity: .4;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all the markup of your `label` is not compatible with the standard i.e it has not the `for` attribute. [See this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) or at least it should wrap its element.

So first, your HTML should be something like the following:

```
<label id="spacesPerIndentLabel" for="spacesPerIndent">Spaces per indent: 4</label>
<br>
<input id="spacesPerIndent" type="text" disabled>
```

Then using javascript we will add class to each label that its for element is disabled like the following:

```
labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
    for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++){
      forId = labels[i].attributes.for.value
      if (document.getElementById(forId).attributes.disabled){
        labels[i].className = 'dis'
      }
    }
```

Checkout [**this DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/yozoqutafa/edit?html,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with putting a wrapper around your input and label that uses position relative, and positioning your label absolutely, you can try this method:

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 1.1em;
}

.container label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.container input[disabled] + label {
  background: grey;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <input id="test1" type="text">
  <label for="test1">Test 1 label</label>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <input id="test2" type="text" disabled>
  <label for="test2">Test 2 label</label>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c1d81r8b/3/

Essentially this just places the label after your inputs so they can be targeted with the sibling selector, but then positions them before it. The `1.1em` padding top on the container is what makes space for the label to sit - adjust this to match your label font size and any required padding/margins there.

Note that this will not be appropriate if your label text needs to wrap at any point - so use with caution.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can do the following (if you have a future release date/only need to support new browsers):

```html
<label>
  Hello
  <input type="text" disabled />
</label>
```

```css
input:disabled {
  background: lightgray;
}

label:has(:disabled) {
  color: lightgray;
}
```